# Force SSL/TLS version for Java RMI server/client

Tags: ssl, java

Everywhere documented, it says Java RMI can apply SSL/TLS. I have a working sample of a client/server application that does exactly this. But how can i force the used protocol to TLS 1.2? I need to make sure that any SSL version or TLS 1.0 is never used.

Comment: I would start with the code from  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/security-83/index.html and replace `TLSv1` with `TLSv1.2` which are options for SSLContext according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and I ended up writing an implementation of RMIServerSocketFactory myself:

```
public class TlsServerSocketFactory implements RMIServerSocketFactory {

    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLServerSocketFactory sf = ((SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault());
        SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) (sf.createServerSocket(port));

        s.setUseClientMode(false);
        s.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"}); // NO POODLES HERE!
        s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites());

        return s;
    }
}
```

It's almost the same procedure for the ClientFactory, but this is not necessary for my needs.
Oh, and I had to get JDK 1.8, as TLS1 was max for 1.6.